# Iptables: Allow Internal LAN to access INTERNET

Tags: networking, home-networking, lan, iptables, nat

I have an internal network behind my router on eth0, and I have my router connected to the internet thorugh wlan0. I can't access the internet from inside the lan, how can I fix this?

```
wlan0: 192.168.1.108
eth0:  10.1.1.0/24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the same deal as if it was connected directly to the Internet. Enable NAT, configure your clients to use 192.168.1.108 as Gateway and 10.1.1.1 (or whatever your actual router IP is) as Primary DNS and end of story.

If you want 192.168.1.108 to be the DNS provider aswell, you will have to configure it to relay DNS requests to the actual router.

Answer (score 0):

Both 192.168/16 and 10/8 are not routable on the Internet. Your router can't be on the Internet if it has that reserved address. You'll need to find out why it was assigned that address.

Comment: The router is actually just a computer connected wirelessly to the actual-router. The computer is acting like a router to the internal network.

Comment: OK, so can you do anything from your 10.1.1/24 network? Can you ping the computer-router? The actual-router? Does DNS work on the 10.1.1/24 network? What program are you using to provide router functionality?

Comment: I can ping the computer-router from 10.1.1/24 but I can't ping the actual-router. I am just trying to use NAT with the iptables and ip_forward

Comment: Squillions of things could be wrong. The router software on the computer-router is probably misconfigured. What OS and what router software is computer-router running? Can you ping the 10.1.1/24 machines from computer-router?

Comment: I can access everything that is on 10.1.1/24 on all the computers on it but all I want to do is let the computers on 10.1.1/24 access outside networks. I am running debian, and dont have any "router" software. I am running dhcp assigning static addresses on 10.1.1/24

Comment: Some software must be providing the router functionality on your computer-router box. I wanted to know what program that was, because if I don't know what it is, I can't debug it. It sounds as if you are using iptables to allow your computer-router to act as a NAT router for the 10.1.1/24 network. Manually configuring iptables can be challenging. Have you tried any of the configuration wizards for iptables?